# Handling Latex backslashes in xtable

Tags: r, latex, sweave

I have a table that includes the following column:

```
 mytable <- data.frame(beta_0 = c(1,2,3)
```

What I want to do is output a table with a column header in latex markup, e.g. `$\beta_0$`

However, I can not seem to figure out how to output the "$\beta_0$" using `print.xtable`:

```
colnames(mytable) <- "$\beta_0$"
library(xtable)
print(xtable(mytable), include.rownames = F)
```

returns a column header of

```
\eta\_0\$
```

instead of

```
$\beta_0$
```

I presume that the answer is the "sanitize.colnames.function" argument to `print.xtable`, but it is not obvious to me how to use this, and `?print.xtable` provides no examples.

Specifically, I would like to output a latex table like:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
 \begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{r}
    \hline
    $\beta_0$ \\ 
    \hline
    1.00 \\ 
    2.00 \\ 
    3.00 \\ 
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
 \end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32865384/function-to-sanitize-strings-for-latex-compilation

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Two issues here; first, you need a double backslash as otherwise it treats it as a control sequence.  Second, by default, `xtable` sanitizes text so that it won't break LaTeX.  Use one of the `sanitize.` parameters to control this; to do no sanitizing, pass it the identity function.

```
colnames(mytable) <- "$\\beta_0$"
print(xtable(mytable), include.rownames = F, sanitize.colnames.function = identity)
```

Comment: I had tried the double backslashes, but it was the `sanitize.colnames.function` that perplexed me. Is there a list of possible values for the `sanitize*` arguments?

Comment: @David There is not a list of possible values for the `sanitize` arguments. As it clearly says in the docs: `it should be a function taking a character vector and returning one, and will be used for the sanitization instead of the default internal function`. Aaron has simply passed `identity` which is a function that does nothing.

Comment: It takes any suitable function. `identity` is a base function that does nothing.

Comment: got it: `identity <- function(x)x`. @joran I saw that part, I was curious to see if there were particular functions that are particularly useful with parsing "\"'s and other latex markup. But `identity` has solved my current issue.

Comment: I don't know of any other particular functions that are out there; when I've needed something more complex I've started with the default one in xtable and modified it to meet my needs.

Comment: @David you can always grep the source for a list of `sanitize` arguments: They are: `sanitize.rownames.function`, `sanitize.colnames.function`, `sanitize.text.function`, and can be set with `options` instead of as arguments to print, e.g. `options(xtable.sanitize.rownames.function=identity)`

Answer (score 3):

this is what did the trick for me:

```
mat <- round(matrix(c(0.9, 0.89, 200, 0.045, 2.0), c(1, 5)), 4)
rownames(mat) <- "$y_{t-1}$"
colnames(mat) <- c("$R^2$", "$\\bar{x}$", "F-stat", "S.E.E", "DW")
mat <- xtable(mat)
print(mat, sanitize.text.function = function(x){x})
```

This way you avoid the backslash issue in the table text.